# problem with nested observables and loading content in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, get, observable

I'm starting to make my first app in angular using a weather api, in a first loading view I want to make 3 requests by subscribing to observables, all three of type get and each one depends on the following:

1 - Get the list of all states
2 - Get the list of the departments of each state
3 - Obtain the prediction of a department from each random state

The problem I want to face is that, when making different concatenated requests, I don't want to load the table with the data until all the load is finished, but this is making me very difficult since I have tried to put a loading variable at the beginning of the code and another at the end of the for that exists between point 2 and 3 but it does not work as desired.

My code is the following:

general.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { eltiempoDataService } from 'src/app/services/eltiempo-data.service';
import { weatherGeneralModel } from 'src/app/models/weatherGeneral.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-general',
  templateUrl: './general.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./general.component.css']
})
export class GeneralComponent implements OnInit {

  data_mun: weatherGeneralModel[] = [];
  loading_data: boolean;

  constructor(private eltiempoDataService: eltiempoDataService) {
    this.getRandomMunicipio()
    console.log('finish2')
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getRandomMunicipio() {
    let provs
    let prov_random: {}
    this.getProvincias().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      this.loading_data = true;
      provs = data['provincias']
      this.processData(provs)
    })
  }

  processData(provs: any[]){
    for (let prop in provs) {
      this.getMunicipios(provs[prop]['CODPROV']).subscribe((data_municipios) => {
        let object_data_general: weatherGeneralModel = new weatherGeneralModel()
        let local_muni: any[] = data_municipios['municipios']
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * local_muni.length);
        let cod_ine_mun = local_muni[random]['CODIGOINE'].toString().substring(0, 5);
        this.getDataMunicipio(provs[prop]['CODPROV'], cod_ine_mun).subscribe((data_predict) => {
          object_data_general.comunidad = provs[prop]['COMUNIDAD_CIUDAD_AUTONOMA']
          object_data_general.provincia = provs[prop]['NOMBRE_PROVINCIA']
          object_data_general.municipio = data_predict['municipio']['NOMBRE']
          object_data_general.pronostico = data_predict['temperaturas']['max'] + '/' + data_predict['temperaturas']['min']
          object_data_general.cod_prov = provs[prop]['CODPROV']
          this.data_mun.push(object_data_general)
        })
      })
    }
    this.loading_data = false;
  }

  getProvincias() {
    return this.eltiempoDataService.getProvincias()
  }

  getMunicipios(cod_prov: string) {
    return this.eltiempoDataService.getMunicipios(cod_prov)
  }

  getDataMunicipio(cod_prov: string, id_muni: string) {
    return this.eltiempoDataService.getDataMunicipio(cod_prov, id_muni)
  }
}
```

eltiempo-dataService.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class eltiempoDataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('servicio ElTiempo.net listo')
  }

  getProvincias(){
    return this.http.get('https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias')
  }

  getMunicipios(cod_prov:string){
    return this.http.get(`https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias/${cod_prov}/municipios`)
  }

  getDataMunicipio(cod_prov:string, id_muni:string){
    return this.http.get(`https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias/${cod_prov}/municipios/${id_muni}`)
  }
}
```

general.component.html:

```
 
<div class="contianer mt-5 m-sm-5">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-dark" *ngIf="!loading_data">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Comunidad</th>
          <th scope="col">Provincia</th>
          <th scope="col">Muicipio</th>
          <th scope="col">Prediccion</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of data_mun">
          <th scope="row">{{data.CODPROV}}</th>
          <td>{{data.comunidad}}</td>
          <td>{{data.provincia}}</td>
          <td>{{data.municipio}}</td>
          <td>{{data.pronostico}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I assume I am not following best practice and would appreciate any help, advice and guidance.

Thank you all

Comment: Check if this helps: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166467/chaining-3-dependent-http-request-subscriptions-one-which-is-polling or this also https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handle-multiple-api-requests-in-angular-using-mergemap-and-forkjoin-to-avoid-nested-subscriptions-a20fb5040d0c

Comment: You'll need to put `this.loading_data = false;` in the deepest nested subscribe because subscribes are `async` so your flag will most of the time be executed before the data is actually loaded. Also you should not nests `subscribes`, it gives timing errors and it will be harder to do error handling. [This article will explain what to do instead of using nested subscriptions](https://www.thinktecture.com/de/angular/rxjs-antipattern-1-nested-subs/) or you can check the [RxJS website](https://rxjs.dev/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is StackBlitz Link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-api-calls-forkjoin?file=src/app/app.component.ts

First I suggest creating interfaces for all your endpoints because it's the power of typescript, you will get a lot of help from your IDE because it knows what kind of data you will be getting.

I exported some of your endpoints interfaces to see how it works:

```
export interface Municipios {
  breadcrumb: {
    name: string;
    title: string;
    url: string;
  }[];
  codprov: string;
  keywords: string;
  metadescripcion: string;
  municipios: Municipio[];
  provincia: string;
  title: string;
}
```

and in your service it will be like this.

```
  getMunicipios(cod_prov: string): Observable<Municipios> {
    return this.http.get<Municipios>(
      `https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias/${cod_prov}/municipios`
    );
  }
```

Second: Services, Interfaces and Classes Naming convention is PascalCase
so `eltiempoDataService` will be `EltiempoDataService`

third: since you need data from first array which is result of your first API requests then you can use `forkJoin` to simply send all requests all together and when they all are ready you can use the answer.
forkJoin: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

so here you can create an array which has province and observable of next data you need.

```
    this.loading_data = true;
    const provinciasGetMunicipiosObservables: {
      province: Province;
      getMunicipios: Observable<Municipios>;
    }[] = [];

    const getDataMunicipioObservables: { // This is for second wave of API Calls
      province: Province;
      municipios: Municipios;
      getDataMunicipio: Observable<DataMunicipio>;
    }[] = [];

    provincias.forEach(province => {
      /***************************
       **** Creating Array of province and  getMunicipios observable
       ***************************/
      provinciasGetMunicipiosObservables.push({
        province,
        getMunicipios: this.getMunicipios(province.CODPROV)
      });
    });
```

and when your array is ready you can pass it to forkJoin and when result of all of them is ready it will give the answer.

note: because I didn't create an absolute array of observables I needed to `map` the Observable only so It returns an array of Observables

And pipe inside observable is for mapping answer of that specific Observable and when It had access to province I mapped it inside Answer.

```
    forkJoin(
      provinciasGetMunicipiosObservables.map(x => {
        return x.getMunicipios.pipe(
          map(y => {
            return {
              province: x.province,
              getMunicipiosAnswer: y
            };
          })
        );
      })
    )
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(municipiosArray => {
// Time to send Second Wave of API requests

}
```

And simply you can repeat the process Just like before.

```
      .subscribe(municipiosArray => {
        municipiosArray.forEach(municipios => {
          /***************************
           **** Part two of data when we got getMunicipios
           ***************************/
          let local_muni: any[] = municipios.getMunicipiosAnswer.municipios;
          var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * local_muni.length);
          let cod_ine_mun = local_muni[random]["CODIGOINE"]
            .toString()
            .substring(0, 5);
          /***************************
           **** Creating second array for getting getDataMunicipio
           ***************************/
          getDataMunicipioObservables.push({
            municipios: municipios.getMunicipiosAnswer,
            province: municipios.province,
            getDataMunicipio: this.getDataMunicipio(
              municipios.province.CODPROV,
              cod_ine_mun
            )
          });
        });
          /***************************
           **** Send Requests with forkJoin
           ***************************/
        forkJoin(
          getDataMunicipioObservables.map(x => {
            return x.getDataMunicipio.pipe(
              map(y => {
                return {
                  province: x.province,
                  municipios: x.municipios,
                  getDataMunicipioAnswer: y
                };
              })
            );
          })
        ).subscribe(arrayOfFinalData => {
          // temproray array
          const finalData: WeatherGeneral[] = [];
          arrayOfFinalData.forEach(weatherData => {
            const max = weatherData.getDataMunicipioAnswer.temperaturas.max;
            const min = weatherData.getDataMunicipioAnswer.temperaturas.min;
            const pronostico = `${max}/${min}`;
            const weatherGeneral = new WeatherGeneral({
              cod_prov: weatherData.province.CODPROV,
              comunidad: weatherData.province.COMUNIDAD_CIUDAD_AUTONOMA,
              municipio: weatherData.getDataMunicipioAnswer.municipio.NOMBRE,
              pronostico,
              provincia: weatherData.province.NOMBRE_PROVINCIA
            });
            finalData.push(weatherGeneral);
          });
           this.loading_data = false;
          this.data_mun = [...finalData];
        });
      });
```

And feel free to ask if something was unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response and your involvement in the tests.

I am still very new to Angular programming and have overlooked the style guides on naming and formatting, thank you very much for those remarks as well.

I will read and understand your answer and implement it and I will tell you the results. Thanks again.

Comment: hi! finally i have managed implement this solution!

i had to do some changes for adapt the code, because it in your example provided only for two waves request.

That means that not was only copy paste but to understand.

i have implemented three forkjoin concatenated, beginning for getting province list, and all works perfectly!

maybe this was not the best first example for learn how forkjoins works, but was a great explain and i get it!
 thanks guy!

Comment: Awesome. only problem with forkJoin might be if one of those requests throw an error it will break the whole requests so I suggest using retry operator or some other way to make sure it works perfectly. Goodluck

Comment: understood! i will read about retry for catch possible errors or issues! thx!